# Weird capacitor looking things shows up in altium when I zoom into the pcb layout

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout

I am using altium for first time for my little circuit project. My layout start showing these weird capacitor looking things in PCB layout. What exactly are they and what are they used for and how do I disable them to show up on layout?

[image]

Comment: Looks like parasitic capacitors. Altium is trying to show you the electrical characteristics of your board layout. It'll only really matter for high speed circuits.

Comment: how do i disable them to show up.

Comment: Nothing to do with capacitors. Spehro's answer is correct.

Answer (score 13):

That comes from running a design rule check with no traces routed. It is showing you the rubber band connections that are not complete.

Go to Tools->Reset Error Markers to get rid of them. The rubber band lines will stay but the 'capacitor' error markers will go away.

Comment: Perfect! That just worked!

Answer (score 1):

That's a broken net. They will disappear as you route traces and run a DRC.